# "AllowOverride not allowed here" in WAMP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp

I have enabled `mod_rewrite` (it's checked in the WAMP icon in my taskbar and uncommented in `httpd.conf`) and I've made sure any `AllowOverride` settings in `httpd.conf` are set to `All`, yet I'm still getting a `500` error message and

`[alert] [client 127.0.0.1] E:/mywebsite/html/.htaccess: AllowOverride not allowed here`

in my Apache error log.

Could it be a result of changing the `DocumentRoot` to a completely different one? I installed WAMP on `D:\` and changed the root to my Dropbox folder on `E:\`.

Is there an extra conf file WAMP has that sets special settings like XAMPP does?

**Why am I still getting this error?** I've searched the internet high and low for an answer, yet they all tell me to enable that module and I have done.

On Windows 7, WAMP 2.2.

Comment: It seems you have  a `AllowOverride` line in `E:/mywebsite/html/.htaccess`

Comment: I read that you needed to include `AllowOverride` in your `.htaccess` file, but it seems not. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just moving my comment as answer since it seems to have resolved OP's problem.

Looking at error it seems there is a `AllowOverride` line in `E:/mywebsite/html/.htaccess` and  Apache is throwing 500 error because `AllowOverride` isn't allowed in `.htaccess`.